# one log file for several batch processes locks up

Tags: batch-file, logging

I have very basic batch file knowledge.  My first script was something I found to export Oracle Discoverer reports via windows task scheduler.  That's basically all I know, I've got several of them (maybe 40 or so) that run at various times, some every 30 mins.  They sometimes overlap in time.

My issue is not the specific discoverer export, but the logging of errors.  I want to log everything to a single log file...  with excel and access processes, I can loop until free and all is good; with the discoverer batch files, the log file gets locked at the beginning and doesn't let anything else log in until done.  Some of these discoverer reports may take 30 mins or more, messing up all my runs.

Here's an example of my bat file:

```
@echo off
echo my process %date% %time% >>c:\test.log
c:\orant\DISCVR4\DIS4USR.EXE /connect MyUserID/MyPassword@myserver /open "c:\DiscoReport.DIS" /export xls "c:\MyFile.xls" /batch 1>>c:\test.log 2>>&1
```

I have a bat file with several of those individual process bat files, so that they run one at a time.  That works fine.  But when the run takes longer than estimated, then the next run fails... because they all start by running disco, and the log file is locked throughout and until the end...  Is there something I can do to just open and close it right at the time of adding the results only?

I've looked for answers, and I believe there's something that might be done with the TEE or redirecting the results maybe to null and then using that as input piped to write to the log?  but I don't really know how to do this... looked, tried, weeks and weeks, can't get anything working...  Pretty please, I'm sure those who know, can do this with one single line.. Pls help...

Comment: I don't quite follow, but if you use a date/time stamp in the logfilename (test-yyyyddmm-hhss.log) then it will create separate logs and they can be copied together (sorted by time) into one file.  The filename as shown will sort by time correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, NO - if you want the log file to contain all events in time-order.

You could have the discoverer processes create their individual logfiles and then

```
type discoverer.log.file >>logfile
del discoverer.log.file
```

which would group all of the discoverer process output together in the logfile.

Otherwise, you'd have to put up with more than one log.

I severely doubt `TEE` could do it as `TEE` would then itself need to hold the log open, so you're back at the start - *But I'll emphasise I haven't tried it.*